# Javascript underscore array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Is there an easy/clean way using Underscore to turn this

```
[ { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
  { id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
  { id: 'high',   votes: 5 } ]
```

Into

```
 { 'low'    : 9,
   'medium' : 7,
   'high'   : 5 }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var data = [ { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
  { id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
  { id: 'high',   votes: 5 } ];
```

You can do this with [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map), [`_.values`](http://underscorejs.org/#values) and [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object), like this

```
console.log(_.object(_.map(data, _.values)));
# { medium: 7, low: 9, high: 5 }
```

**Explanation**

We use the `map` function to apply the `values` function (which gets all the values of a given object) over all the elements of `data`, which would give

```
# [ [ 'medium', 7 ], [ 'low', 9 ], [ 'high', 5 ] ]
```

Then we use `object` function to transform this into an object.

Comment: An interesting answer, but perhaps you could clarify what data is firstly, eg data = x;

Comment: I used Krasimir's answer, but you answered the question using underscore and there is more to learn for anyone interested in that sort of thing.

Comment: @TheBigC Always favor functional way. That will make the code more readable, less prone to errors :)

Comment: @dewd Please check the definition of `data`. There was a newline. I just removed it now.

Comment: I prefer using `indexBy` for  readability. This solution might be quite hard to understand for others.

Comment: How can you be sure that _.values({id: 'medium', votes: 7}) returns ['medium', 7] and not [7, 'medium']?

Comment: this solution is unreliable, relying on ordering of properties in your objects

Answer (score 43):

You might consider _.indexBy(...)

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jon Doe',
    birthdate: '1/1/1991',
    height: '5 11'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane Smith',
    birthdate: '1/1/1981',
    height: '5 6'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Rockin Joe',
    birthdate: '4/4/1994',
    height: '6 1'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Jane Blane',
    birthdate: '1/1/1971',
    height: '5 9'
}, ];

var transformed = _.indexBy(data, 'id');
```

Here is a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4vyLtcrf/3/

**Update:** In Lodash 4.0.1 the method _.indexBy has been renamed to _.keyBy

Comment: +1 for readability. Worth noting that the `id` property will still be present in the resulting objects, but that should be okay in most cases (and easy to post-exclude in others).

Comment: A similar solution for those looking to have each key in the final object as an *array* of items with that key (as opposed to a single item), there's also `_.groupBy()`

Answer (score 8):

Here is with vanilla js:

```
var result = {};
[ { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
  { id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
  { id: 'high',   votes: 5 } ].forEach(function(obj) {
    result[obj.id] = obj.votes;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

simpler with me: `each`:

```
   var t = {};
   _.each(x, function(e){
     t[e.id] = e.votes;
   });
//--> {medium: 7, low: 9, high: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most powerfull method of underscore is reduce. You can do almost anything with it. And the bigger benefit is you iterate over the collection only ONCE!

```
var array = [ 
    { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
    { id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
    { id: 'high',   votes: 5 } 
];
var object = _.reduce(array, function(_object, item) { 
    _object[item.id] = item.votes; 
    return _object; 
}, {});
```

After it runs, object will be:

```
{
  medium:7,
  low:9,
  high:5
}
```

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to dynamically add new properties to an object in JavaScript. https://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html

Comment: Got it! That said @morio, what is your suggested solution?

Comment: Hm, you got me. Now I think about it, I don't know if there a way to avoid this. I guess libraries like Lodash are doing the same thing internally.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexBy

```
_.indexBy([ 
   { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
   { id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
   { id: 'high',   votes: 5 } 
 ], 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but you could use `_.reduce` to do the transform in a clean way

```
var data = [
    { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
    { id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
    { id: 'high',   votes: 5 }
]

var output = _.reduce(data, function(memo, entry) {
    memo[entry.id] = entry.votes;
    return memo;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with native JS Array.reduce

```
const myArray = [ { id: 'medium', votes: 7 },
{ id: 'low',    votes: 9 },
{ id: 'high',   votes: 5 } ]

const myObject = myArray.reduce((obj, item)=>{
  o[item.id] = item.votes
  return o
}, {})
```

for more details, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce