# convert array into object using underscore only

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I am learning underscore now and found a task for it I need help with .. I have an array with object looking like this

```
[
    // ...
    {
            "type": "presence",
            "params": {
                "interval": 15,
                "foo": "something",
                "link": {
                    "fp_type": "1",
                    "fp_ext_id": "2"
            },
    },
    {
            "type": "bar",
            "params": {
                "interval": 30,
                "foo": "foo",
                "link": {
                    "fp_type": "2",
                    "fp_ext_id": "3"
                },
            },
    },
    // ...
]
```

The task is using underscore only to convert this array items to an object where the 
the key is the items type and the value are its params, i.e.:

```
{
  // ...
  "presence": {
    "interval": 15,
    "foo": "something",
    "link": {
        "fp_type": "1",
        "fp_ext_id": "2"
     },
  }, 
  "bar": {
       "interval": 30,
       "foo": "foo",
       "link": {
           "fp_type": "2",
           "fp_ext_id": "3"
       },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript underscore array to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427560/javascript-underscore-array-to-object)

Comment: @GeorgeJemptyI could not think of a better title but the question has a slight difference.

Comment: If it only has a slight difference you should at least be able to use that to show us some code you actually tried

Comment: the closest solution I got to this was something like the answer of @hd84335  

`var y = _.map(x, function(i) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[i.type] = i.params;
  return obj;
});

var result = Object.assign({}, ...y);` But I still don't like the solution and think that is not okay with the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```js
var x = [    
    {
            "type": "presence",
            "params": {
                "interval": 15,
                "foo": "something",
                "link": {
                    "fp_type": "sponsor",
                    "fp_ext_id": "spotme"
                },
            },
    },
    {
            "type": "bar",
            "params": {
                "interval": 30,
                "foo": "foo",
                "link": {
                    "fp_type": "2",
                    "fp_ext_id": "3"
                },
            },
    }
];

var y = _.map(x, function(i) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[i.type] = i.params;
  return obj;
});
//console.log(y);

var result = y.reduce(function(obj,item) { 
  obj[_.keys(item)[0]] = _.values(item)[0]; 
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hd84335/ypebcy7b/)

Comment: this returns array with 2 objects in this example.  the point is to convert the array to a single object with key which is the type and value which are the params ( they may be nested )

Comment: which type to select as a key if you have multiple types? and for the value, will it be an array?

Comment: you will have multiple keys in the object with values that come from the params

Comment: I updated the example to help you understand the task :). the second code snipped should be the returned object composed from the first code snipped

Comment: i got what you want! check now how it is done. here is a link on the main problem i think you are facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Comment: It's almost the desired result. The first thing that I find is that this returns an object which is array and you can access it with y[0] or y[1]. in the requirements the output should be an object and in this example, the top key values should be "presence1" and "bar". Thanks for the effort trying to help me !

Comment: mm here it is... this question is tricky, thanks to ES6 which provides a method that makes the conversion!

Comment: Yes, it is :) I kinda feel like this is a cheat, in the end, using Object.assign to convert it to an object. Anyway if no one gives a better solution soon I will accept your answer

Comment: mmm it's not a cheat, that's ECMA6 official! Anyways, if you don't want to use it, we can break it down and use pure `underscorejs` to solve this. i update

Comment: If you can I will be glad, because I am kinda new underscore. The assignment is to use only underscore